# Is there a way to transmit the computers location via WGET?

Tags: wget, location

I have a little script which pings my server by fetching a web address via WGET. The idea is, should my computer ever go missing, I have a chance of tracking it down.

Is there any way to add additional information (particularly location) into the request?

Comment: The `wget` and the request and response are not the problem. The problem is to find out the server's location.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. WGET runs from my computer and the remote address logs my IP etc..

Comment: Ahh, so you want to track/locate the machine thut runs `wget`, not the server. I misunderstood that.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [this stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121269/how-to-talk-to-geoclue-through-its-dbus-interface), you may use information from:

```
qdbus --literal org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Providers.UbuntuGeoIP /org/freedesktop/Geoclue/Providers/UbuntuGeoIP org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Position.GetPosition
```

To get other providers, look at:

```
apt search ^geoclue-
```

There is not much documentation on those other providers, but you may look at the service file in

```
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/
```